# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. Dictionaries within lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I am making a small program which is making a dictionary out of values from another dictionary. However I've hit a snag with the syntax for this.
Here is the code:

```
first_dict = {}
new_list_of_dict = [{"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"},
                    {"name": "Johno"}]
for i in new_list_of_dict:
    print(i["name"])
    first_dict[i] = i["name"]
    print(first_dict)
```

I want to give `first_dict` the key `name` and then set the value to `Johno`. I also need the solution to be expandable to multiple keys with values that are different data types such as lists and integers.

Comment: Keys for a dictionary [must provide `__hash__`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys). Mutable datatypes cannot provide a stable hash function.  Please read that link for further explanation.

Comment: add a comma after the first element in `new_list_of_dict`

Comment: I'm not trying to make a list the key. The key should be name whilst the value is Johno. I would however like to make the value a list sometime in the future, but this much I know is possible.

Comment: `i` is each of `new_list_of_dict`s dictionaries. You can't use a dictionary as a key. I'm not sure what you're trying to get `first_dict` to look like when you're done

Comment: @AdamSmith I am trying to make it so that I can grab multiple specific keys and value pairs from one dictionary and put them in the other.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are making the dict `i` as the key of dict `first_dict`. Hence, the `unhashable` error. Try this instead:

```
for i in new_list_of_dict:
    for key, value in i.items():
        first_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: But, what if I don't want all of the keys in a dictionary and I only want to target a few. Say for example there is one dictionary with keys 1,2,3,4 and I want to make a new dictionary with only keys 1 and 3

Comment: You will have to embed that logic, for the keys that you want to skip.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each element in `new_list_of_dict` has one key-value pair:

`dict([d.items()[0] for d in new_list_of_dict])`

Explanation: `items()` returns a list of the dictionary's key-value pairs, where each element in the list is a tuple `(key, value)`. Since we assume this list contains only one element, we take the first, and use list comprehension to create a list of such tuples, i.e.:

```
[('name', 'Johno'),
('name', 'Johno'),
      ...

('name', 'Johno')]
```

Finally we convert it to a dictionary.

In order to select specific indices, first select the indices you want:

`inds = [1,3]`

then select the new list and convert:

`dict([d.items()[0] for d in [new_list_of_dict[i] for i in inds]])`